# a word for water after it falls

Tags: nouns, vocabulary

Is there a word ( noun ) that refers to the condition/ place at the base of a waterfall where the water that has fallen over upsurges upon hitting the bottom and rolls back on itself before continuing downstream ? I watched a child's ball caught in this, rolling on itself unable to float further with the flow.

Answer (score 5):

I think the phrase you're looking for is *[plunge pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunge_pool)*.

> "A plunge pool (or plunge basin or waterfall lake) is a depression at the base of a waterfall created by the falling water scouring where it lands."